# JavaScript:How to modify the values in an array while the iteration happening?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Hi Javascript Newbie question,

```
var aarr = [
 {
    "label": "Name",
    "visible": true,
    "value": "HOW"
 },
 {
    "label": "Age",
    "visible": false,
    "value": "23"
 },
 {
    "label": "goodToGo",
    "visible": false,
    "value": "Yes"
 },
 {
    "label": "authenticatedflag",
    "visible": true,
    "value": "No"
 }
];
```

Scenario: (How can i achieve this logic within in single loop)

In need to modify the above array based on this conditions:

> E.g: if label === "Name" && "value" === "HOW" then Modify Age.value to
>   "27" and authenticatedflag.value to "No", in the same loop itself,
>   label === "Age" && "value" === "27" then, modify the goodToGo.value to
>   No and authenticatedflag.value to "Yes"

Part of the code would.

```
aarr.map(aObj => {
    if(aObj.label === "Name" && aObj.value === "HOW") {
        // In this case i need to modify the aarr contents
    }
    // Before this loop executes the aarr contents should be changed.
    if(aObj.label === "Age" && aObj.value === "27") {
        // Once again modify the contents of the array before passing to next condition
    }
});
```

Comment No:2 by @Tushar Seems to work half

```
if (arr.find(o => o.label === 'Name' && o.value === 'HOW')) {
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'Age').value = 27;
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'authenticatedflag').value = 'No';
} else if (arr.find(o => o.label === 'Age' && o.value === '27')) {
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'goodToGo').value = 'No';
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'authenticatedflag').value = 'Yes';
}

console.log(arr);

/*
[ { label: 'Name', visible: true, value: 'HOW' },
  { label: 'Age', visible: false, value: 27 },
  { label: 'goodToGo', visible: false, value: 'Yes' },
  { label: 'authenticatedflag', visible: true, value: 'No' } ]
*/
```

In this case only one condition get satisfied actually it needs to satisfy both the conditions.

Comment: `map` will replace the value in the current iteration with whatever you `return`, so simply modify `aObj` and then return it.

Comment: `if (arr.find(o => o.label === 'Name' && o.value === 'HOW')) {
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'Age').value = 27;
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'authenticatedflag').value = 'No';
} else if (arr.find(o => o.label === 'Age' && o.value === '27')) {
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'goodToGo').value = 'No';
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'authenticatedflag').value = 'Yes';
}`

Comment: Thanks Marty and Tushar, if will look into both of suggestions. And @Marty how to modify two values in the same array while using map, i need to to another map on the same array when the condition met ?

Comment: Oops too newbie, i think some one wasted 2 points to downvote my question :). Anyway from my point of view this is newbie question.

Comment: @Marty—saying *map* "replaces" is misleading. It creates a new array from the returned values, it doesn't modify the array in–place (though it can be used for that, *forEach* would be more appropriate).

Comment: Why are you using an array for this? and not an object? will the array change so that authenticatedFlag will no longer be last nor Age second (etc)?

Comment: @RobG Hmm yes, replace is not the right word, I couldn't think of a way to put it briefly without getting too detailed (I'm not good with words at the best of times).

Comment: If you can change it to an object literal then this structure will be more helpful for what you are trying to achieve:

    {
        "Name": {
            "visible": true,
            "value": "HOW"
        },
        "Age": {
            "visible": false,
            "value": "23"

        },
        "goodToGo": {
            "visible": false,
            "value": "Yes"

        },
        "authenticatedflag": {
            "visible": true,
            "value": "No"

        }
    }

Comment: @tudor.gergely But that is the data structure I am getting as response from a service call, I can change the response to your model, but can you post a sample snippet of how can i achieve both two conditions. :) Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: definetly, take your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify the structure of you array (if possible) to something more appropiate:

```
var obj = {
    "Name": {
        "visible": true,
        "value": "HOW"
    },
    "Age": {
        "visible": false,
        "value": "23"

    },
    "goodToGo": {
        "visible": false,
        "value": "Yes"

    },
    "authenticatedflag": {
        "visible": true,
        "value": "No"

    }
}
```

This will help you do things like:

```
if (obj.Name.value === 'HOW') {
    obj.Age.value = 27;
    obj.authenticatedFlag.value = 'No';
}

if (obj.Age.value === 27) {
    obj.goodToGo.value = 'No';
    obj.authenticatedFlag.value = 'Yes';
}
```

And even more.

If you cannot modify the structure itself I would still try and convert the array itself: https://jsfiddle.net/43w4c06n/

```
var arr = [
    {
        "label": "Name",
        "visible": true,
        "value": "HOW"
    }, {
        "label": "Age",
        "visible": false,
        "value": "23"
    }, {
        "label": "goodToGo",
        "visible": false,
        "value": "Yes"
    }, {
        "label": "authenticatedflag",
        "visible": true,
        "value": "No"
    },
];

var res = arr.map(function (item) {
    var result = {};
    result[item.label] = {
        visible: item.visible,
        value: item.value
    };
    return result;
}).reduce(function (acc, it) {
    return Object.assign(acc, it);
});
```

This will convert your array to the structure I proposed (in case you cannot change the response from the server).

LE: I have now seen you are using ES2015 (I am glad you do :) ). Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oLkdcrs1/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me analyse and check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{
    "label": "Name",
    "visible": true,
    "value": "HOW"
}, {
    "label": "Age",
    "visible": false,
    "value": "23"
}, {
    "label": "goodToGo",
    "visible": false,
    "value": "Yes"
}, {
    "label": "authenticatedflag",
    "visible": true,
    "value": "No"
}];

/* if (arr.find(o => o.label === 'Name' && o.value === 'HOW')) {
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'Age').value = 27;
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'authenticatedflag').value = 'No';
} 

if (arr.find(o => o.label === 'Age' && o.value === '27')) {
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'goodToGo').value = 'No';
    arr.find(o => o.label === 'authenticatedflag').value = 'Yes';
}

console.log(arr); */

/*
[ { label: 'Name', visible: true, value: 'HOW' },
  { label: 'Age', visible: false, value: 27 },
  { label: 'goodToGo', visible: false, value: 'Yes' },
  { label: 'authenticatedflag', visible: true, value: 'No' } ]
*/

var a = arr.map(aObj => {
    if(aObj.label === "Name" && aObj.value === "HOW") {
        arr.find(o => o.label === "Age").value = '27';
        arr.find(o => o.label === "authenticatedflag").value = 'No';
    }
    if(aObj.label === "Age" && aObj.value === '27') {
        arr.find(o => o.label === 'goodToGo').value = 'No';
        arr.find(o => o.label === 'authenticatedflag').value = 'Yes';
    }
    return aObj;
});

/*

[ { label: 'Name', visible: true, value: 'HOW' },
  { label: 'Age', visible: false, value: '27' },
  { label: 'goodToGo', visible: false, value: 'No' },
  { label: 'authenticatedflag', visible: true, value: 'Yes' } ]

*/
```

This seems to satisfies my condition. But is this only way ? or is there any good way to modify the values ??